# Why am I obtaining this error message (No overload matches this call.) when I try to subscribe .valueChanges() retrieving data from Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I am working on an Angular application using Firebase Firestore database via angularfire2 library and I have the following problem.

I state that I am not so into TypeScript (I came from Java) and probably I have some missing knowledge in this topic.

Basically I have a method like this:

```
fetchCompletedOrCancelledExercise() {
    //return this.exercises.slice();
    this.db
        .collection('finishedExercises')
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
            this.finishedExercisesChanged.next(exercises);
        });
}
```

Basically it is retrieving an array of **Exercise** object when something change on Firestore in order to emit this array as an event via a Subject.

The IDE (but also the console when it tries to compile) give me an error on this piece of code **exercises: Exercise[]** (the arrow function param). The error is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<unknown[]>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(exercises: Exercise[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<unknown[]>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: unknown[]) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(exercises: Exercise[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'exercises' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Exercise[]'.
```

Reading at the error and checking what the **.valueChanges()** method returns (this: **Partial<Observer<unknown[]>> | undefined**) the problem seems to be the **Exercise[]** type declared in my subscribe().

So changing my method in this way (removing the type):

```
fetchCompletedOrCancelledExercise() {
    //return this.exercises.slice();
    this.db
        .collection('finishedExercises')
        .valueChanges()
        //.subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
            .subscribe((exercises) => {
            this.finishedExercisesChanged.next(exercises);
        });
}
```

it works fine.

The thing that I am not understanding is that in a tutorial that I am following it uses this type.

Another solution was to disable the TypeScript strict mode.

Basically I suspect that the problem is that my **.valueChanges()** returns **Observable<unknown[]>** an Observable containing a generic array of a not specified type). So if the strict mode is enabled it can't automatically cast the element of this array into my **Exercise** model object. Is it my reasoning correct?

And in case this lead me to another question: is it this strict mode so important? or in this case could be more important disable the strict mode but be allowed to specify the type?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the infer type mechanism of typescript.
Have you try?

```
fetchCompletedOrCancelledExercise() {
   this.db
    .collection<Exercise[]>('finishedExercises')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe((exercises) => {
        this.finishedExercisesChanged.next(exercises);
    });
```

}

So typescript will know your exercises is `Exercise[]`